# Appcelerator: Cannot create a new project

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to create a new project by appcelerator, but I'm receiving this error:

> "Failed to load command "sdk" Error: Cannot find module 'temp'""

Is there any way to fix this without having to reinstall the whole studio?

Comment: Not sure about your problem specifically unless we go through step by step...But a major hint is to carefully go through the Appcelerator docs on installation and running a new project.

Comment: thanks for your concern , i have posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody faces the same problem in the future U have fixed this issue by downloading all missing modules from http://npmjs.com/package/

Comment: you should've installed Appcelerator following the guides. It should install all dependencies properly